# Going from PNG data to tesseract

Tags: c++, image, png, tesseract

I am trying to move image data from Magick++ to tesseract.

I have the PNG data and some info about it.

And the signature for the tesseract method is:

```
void SetImage(const unsigned char* imagedata, int width, int height, int bytes_per_pixel, int bytes_per_line);
```

The first three arguments I can supply just fine. But bytes_per_pixel and bytes_per_line I'm not so sure about. The image itself has 11564 pixels but the length of the data is only 356 bytes... It's mostly a white image with some text. 11564/356 = 32.48 which obviously is not the correct bytes per pixel. How can I get the right bytes / pixel information? It's ok to just get that for one image on my desktop or something and set it as a constant, all the images I'm processing will have the same format.

Then as far as bytes per line, would that just be image width in pixels * bytes per pixel?

Answer (score 2):

bytes_per_pixel can be obtained from PNG data. They are usually 8, 24 or 32.

bytes_per_line too, but you can compute it doing: bytes_per_pixel * width / 8